# Laravel Loop through model children without repeating

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5, eloquent

How do you get all the model's children with ajax without getting the child repeatedly?

Currently, I pass the parent model on from the controller to the view like this:

```
    public function index($parent_id)
    {
        return view('view', ['parent' => Parent::findOrFail($parent_id)]);
    }
```

And then use the parent model to loop the children.

```
    @foreach($parent->children->shuffle() as @child)
        // Some code
    @endforeach
```

But this approach is has problem when the parent's children get up to 5,000 records. I'm thinking of fetching the children using ajax one by one or any other more efficient ways.

Comment: What if you empty your parent's children array before sending it to the view ?

Comment: Also, if you are in lazy loading, you shouldn't get the children when fetching the parent. Probably your serialization fetch them, you should then put your children array as `$hidden` in your model

Comment: Why would I empty the parent's children? I don't get your point.

Comment: Isn't it what you are looking for ? Getting the parent without the children ?

Comment: No. My point is how to get the parent's children using ajax.

Comment: Why the shuffle?